# Apex: can't use a lookup reference retrieved using SOQL query as a function parameter in a recursive function

Tags: apex, soql

I'm refactoring a recursive function to avoid hitting governor limits on SOQL queries.

In order to keep SOQL queries out of a for loop, I'm using dot notation to retrieve a lookup relation (Residence) that exists on the parent account (household) of the object (wish) being queried.

I had no problem when I had a distinct query on the Household object inside a for loop. But for some reason, I can't use the Residence as the parameter on the recursive call.

Here's my call

```
    // GET THE FOLLOWING DATA FOR EACH WISH AGAINST THE TARGET PROPERTY
    // Wish Name
    // Name and Id of parent Household (ie Owner of this wish)
    // Name and Id of parent Household's Residence (may be null)

    List<Wish__c> wishes = new List<Wish__c>([ SELECT Name, 
                                              Household__c, 
                                              Household__r.name,
                                              Household__r.Residence__c,
                                              Household__r.Residence__r.id,
                                              Household__r.Residence__r.name, 
                                              Property__c, 
                                              Property__r.name 
                                              FROM Wish__c 
                                              WHERE Property__c = :targetProperty.Id]);
```

Which works just fine to get me the id I want

[image: Query tested in SoqlX]

But when I try to use either Household__r.Residence__c or Household__r.Residence__r.id in the call to the recursive function, I get the following error

> Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void findDaisyChains(Integer, Id, DaisyChainFinder.daisyChain, Integer) from the type DaisyChainFinder

The call looks like this

```
findDaisyChains(step+1, thisWish.Household__r.Residence__c, daisyChainToUse, maxSteps); // increment the step and execute recursive call
```

The function is declared as follows

```
private static void findDaisyChains(Integer step, Property__c targetProperty, daisyChain thisDaisyChain, Integer maxSteps)
```

It's expecting a property, but won't accept either way of passing it the id of a property.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Your code doesn't match at all. The line where you share your call has a method named `findDaisyChains` with four parameters. Your method where you share the declaration has a method named `getDaisyChainsFromProperty` with two parameters. Can you **[edit]** your post to include all relevant method declarations? The state of completeness here makes it difficult to assist you.

Comment: Woops. Bad copy paste. Fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LookupField__c` is an Id. As long as it looks up to a single object of the correct type, you can use the `LookupField__r` object, instead:

```
findDaisyChains(step+1, thisWish.Household__r.Residence__r, daisyChainToUse, maxSteps); 
// increment the step and execute recursive call
```